# must declare a body because it's not marked abstract

Tags: c#

I have interface

```
INews.cs
public interface INews{
   int Id {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
   void Add(News news);
   void Remove(News news);
}
```

and I have News.cs which implements that interface

```
public class News : INews {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public void Add(News news);
  public void Remove(News news);
```

}

on compile, I have the following message
**must declare a body because it's not marked abstract**

is that mean that I should declare body inside the constructor of News class?

Comment: The methods Add and Remove are not implemented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its your implementation

```
public class News: INews
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public void Add(News news); //<-- invalid
  public void Remove(News news); //<-- invalid
}
```

should at least be

```
public class News: INews
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public void Add(News news){

  }

  public void Remove(News news){

  }
}
```

Comment: I dont know. You indeed have declared the bodies for `Add` and `Remove`.

Answer (score 9):

Your functions need bodies:

```
public void Add(News news)
{

} 

public void Remove(News news)
{

}
```

Functions without bodies are only allowed in abstract classes.

Answer (score 4):

It means that you have not make your `News` class an `abstract` class.

In a class that is not an `abstract` class, the methods must have implementations, not just declarations.

Answer (score 3):

the method must declare a body if its **not** an `abstract` class

```
public void Add(News news)
{

}

public void Remove(News news)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works.

**The body Must be included within flower brackets**

*Sol:*

```
public void Add(News news)
{

}

public void Remove(News news)
{

}
```

There should be a declaration of any abstract class